# WhichBrowser integration error

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, browser-detection

I am running a html page that integrates [WhichBrowser](https://github.com/NielsLeenheer/WhichBrowser).

As explained in the README file, I have put the following code (in the `<head>` part) :

```
<script>
    (function(){var p=[],w=window,d=document,e=f=0;p.push('ua='+encodeURIComponent(navigator.userAgent));e|=w.ActiveXObject?1:0;e|=w.opera?2:0;e|=w.chrome?4:0;
    e|='getBoxObjectFor' in d || 'mozInnerScreenX' in w?8:0;e|=('WebKitCSSMatrix' in w||'WebKitPoint' in w||'webkitStorageInfo' in w||'webkitURL' in w)?16:0;
    e|=(e&16&&({}.toString).toString().indexOf("\n")===-1)?32:0;p.push('e='+e);f|='sandbox' in d.createElement('iframe')?1:0;f|='WebSocket' in w?2:0;
    f|=w.Worker?4:0;f|=w.applicationCache?8:0;f|=w.history && history.pushState?16:0;f|=d.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen?32:0;f|='FileReader' in w?64:0;
    p.push('f='+f);p.push('r='+Math.random().toString(36).substring(7));p.push('w='+screen.width);p.push('h='+screen.height);var s=d.createElement('script');
    s.src='http://localhost/mysite/libs/whichbrowser/detect.js?' + p.join('&');d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);})();
</script>
```

Then the following code (in the `<body>`) :

```
<script>
Browsers = new WhichBrowser();
alert("You are using " + Browsers);
</script>
```

I'm running on easyPHP, and the .htaccess is taken into account so the .js is parsed by the PHP interpreter.

When running the page (from the server of course), I obtain the following error on the line `Browsers = new WhichBrowser();` : "WhichBrowser is not defined".

What did I made wrong ?

Comment: Dunno, but you should never need to know what browser the user is running. Pretty much the only time it's okay is for benchmarking sites like jsperf...

Comment: has the javascript file (the detect.js) that is loaded by the snippet of code loaded by the time you run the bottom snippet?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol:Do you know a way to force ALL the browsers to react exactly the same on CSS3 behaviours for screen and printing, when you do not have the time and resources to test them all and/or adjust your CSS for all the existing browsers ?

Comment: @PatrickEvans:I guess yes... How would I test this and if not loaded, how may I wait for it to be loaded ?

Comment: @Oliver nope, but I just code by the standards and it seems to work just fine in all major browsers. Except Firefox, but even that one's getting there slowly.

Comment: @Oliver, hook the DOMContentLoaded event, for html5 capable browsers or use [documentReady](https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery.parts/blob/master/jquery.documentReady.js)

Comment: `Do you know a way to force ALL the browsers to react exactly the same on CSS3 behaviours for screen and printing` you really, really should be doing feature detection. It's less effort and more robust.

Comment: @AD7six:The problem is not that the feature is not supported. The problem is that it do not react the same on different browsers. Any way, how do you do a feature selection on css selectors ?

Comment: CSS3 [_selectors_](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3)? Are you wanting to use whichbrowser to detect IE <= 8? You can use [conditional comments](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/fdbff109c987d9802cf2b44355f8f785bbbeed7c/index.html#L2-L5) to determine that quite easily, and for css3 feature detection in general [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), and then of course appropriate polyfils. I recommend you update the question to show how you want to use the result of whichbrowser. All that being said, aiming for exactly the same behavior in all browsers is usually a fools errand.

Comment: @AD7six:No, I want to detect IE8, IE<8, Safari, Opera, and FF<22 and FF>=22.

Comment: @AD7six:The purpose of the question is not why I want to use WhichBrowser, but how I may do to make it work like it should.

Comment: You are simply asking and focussing on the wrong question :). Good luck.

Comment: @AD7six:Thank you, but FYI, I'm focusing on the right question. Do you think that I'm happy to have to track the browser my users use ? Not a second, I promise. But you give a general advice without knowing anything about the constraints I have to deal with. Yes, a hammer is the best tool to put a nail into a wall, but if you have to put it in an emergecy and only have a camera with you, you will certainly break the camera and fix the nail badly, but it may do the job. And that's what I'm facing...

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and fixed it by doing the following:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    Browsers = new WhichBrowser();
    // Put rest of browser detection code here
});
```

The problem is that the script is being called before detect.js is loaded.

Comment: I tried and it seems to works. But why can't I access Browser from elsewhere than in that tiny function. I mean, I have a javascript function I call later, and I'd like to test my Browser there, but it says that Browsers is unknown generating a JS error.

Comment: It's because the ready handler is only called when the DOM is ready, not necessarily when the other assets are loaded. Browser is dependent upon the detect.js file being loaded. The only way to ensure that it is loaded first is to access it within the $(window).on('load') event. That "tiny function" doesn't have to be so tiny. You can put anything inside it, including the js function you want to call later. You could open $(window).on('load') right after you call $(document).ready and close it right before you close that.

Comment: Ok, but I mean, if I call a javscript function far after I'm sure the document is loaded (and $(window).on('load') is triggered), why this function do not recognize Browser ?

Comment: You never know how long it takes all your resources to load. It might be 500 ms or 6 full seconds. The only way you can be sure is with the $(window).on('load') function. The document loading/the DOM being ready is different from external assets being loaded. There is lots of information out there about this. For instance this one makes it very clear: http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/

Comment: Thank you but it's still confusing. If Browsers is recognised into $(window).on('load') (let's say I show an alert from there showing infos from Browsers), I don't see why when I call a function after this alert is displayed, that function do not recognise Browsers. I guess this has nothing to do with the time of load of object, as they are clearly loaded at that time.

Comment: No pb, thank you for your help, I'll keep investigating.

Comment: @Oliver Initiate the variable in a global scope. add a "var Browsers = null; "  Try this code before the window on 'load' statement. So that you can access Browsers in a function called later

Comment: $(document).ready was not working so used $(window).load as per answer and it works. +1

Answer (score 1):

That's because in last line of code snippet link should point to php script not js script, and should be like:

```
s.src='http://localhost/mysite/libs/whichbrowser/detect.php?' + p.join('&');d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);})();
```

**Edit:**
That means that for some reason attached .htaccess file wasn't executed (e.g. rewriting off).